# Fetch related items ordered randomly with eloquent / Larvael 5.x

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Simply put, if I have an Entity that has many related items (hasMany) how can I fetch that entity and it's related items with those related rows being ordered randomly

I fetch like so:

```
 $question = Question::with('categories', 'answers')->where( _some_parameters_ ) ... ->get();
```

How would I shuffle those 'answers' in the resulting object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$question = Question::with(['categories', 'answers' => function($q) {
    $q->orderByRaw('RAND()');
}])->where( _some_parameters_ )
->get();
```

This is only for MySQL though.

Answer (score 0):

To do the "shuffle" in Laravel instead of MySQL:

```
 $question = Question::with('categories', 'answers')->
     where( _some_parameters_ ) ... ->get()->shuffle();
```

Answer (score 0):

In *Laravel 5.2* you can try this code:

```
User::inRandomOrder()->get();
```